# Would it work to add Firebase to my Cordova app using the "web app" approach only?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, firebase

I know there is a Cordova plugin to add Firebase analytics (and others), and I could just set up each platform (iOS/Android/browser/..etc) separately.

But I am wondering, Cordova apps are mainly an html+js files! They are a Website structured into an app. Will it work if I just add the  snippet in my index.html (which Firebase made it for web apps)??

It takes sometime before seeing the results, rather than long term impact of this approach, but have any of you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Firebase storage and Firebase database, you can make it work only with HTML + JS. They are the only two functionalities that I have tested in an Android application using the web approach. However, for receiving push notifications you will need to use a plugin.